# overridePendingTransition not working in Android

Tags: android, animation

The following code is not working for me.

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.slide_up);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.slide_up);
```

and the XML for animation is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="-50"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

I searched the web, saw all the threads from Stack Overflow, but not able to fix this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I made it work out in the following way.

I have removed the

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.slide_up);
```

from the above code and placed it in `onPause()`, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes animations are disabled on the phone.  To check go to settings > display > animation > allow "all animations". This will allow overridePendingTransition to work properly if it was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you activate usb debugging mode, it can disable the transitions effects.
Enter Developer options (where you activated debugging mode), find the user's interface section, check if the animation's transition scale have the animations disabled. If so, set it to .5x. Done!

Answer (score -1):

try startActivity before finish()

Comment: try remove <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="-50"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
and leave only alpha change. see if it shows